# С 2 ноября — почему?

Tags: орфография, предлоги

Неожиданно узнал, что когда двойка написана цифрой, тогда *со* не пишется. Очень странно! Почему так?

Comment: Чтобы двойка не была белой вороной.

Comment: *Чтобы двойка не была белой вороной* — что-то не очень понимаю Вас...

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой - это, видимо, о том, что двойка - единственная цифра, для которой пришлось бы писать "со".

Comment: @behemothus: точно, теперь дошло!

Comment: То же и с ["ко"](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=247656). Тогда и "во 2-м" нужно писать без О.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Из комментария (behemothus): *это, видимо, о том, что двойка - единственная цифра, для которой пришлось бы писать "со".* М-м... "Меня терзают смутные сомнения..." Вот вопрос с Меты: Поздравляем Sharon cо 100000! (https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/545/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc-sharon-c%d0%be-100000) Я сдуру в тексте ответе сделала P. S. (и модератор поправил шапку) : *Мне кажется, что в заголовке лучше использовать предлог "со"* (со 100000; с чем? — со ста тысячами). "Дык" только с двойкой, или сдуру, или есть еще цифирки?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова: да, интересно! Я бы тоже сказал *со 100000.* Но с учётом этого уже не знаю...

Answer (score 2):

Такое правило действительно существует, правда это не орфографическое правило, а полиграфическая рекомендация, не императивная. Поэтому ссылку на авторитетный источник уровня Розенталя привести затруднительно.

Объясняется оно, видимо, тем, что при зрительном восприятии цифры совершенно не обязательно проговаривать всю фразу про себя, как при чтении написанного буквами. И тут важнее унификация использования символа (в данном случае - цифры). Но этот вопрос, распознавание смешанного буквенно-символьного текста, имхо, это отдельный разговор, далекий к тому же от орфографии...

Comment: Спасибо большое! А я в любом случае прочитываю. :)

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой - Вы, как я понимаю, не математик и даже не технарь. А наш брат давно отказался от этого. Встретив запись типа 3,14159 никто не будет повторять это по цифрам. Достаточно запомнить, что это число пи. Так же и с двойкой.

Comment: Да, вот еще что. Когда вы встречаете цифры в английском, скажем, тексте, вы тоже вспоминаете, как они там на языке оригинала звучат? Ну типа "keу F1" - это у вас на подкорке "Эф Ван"?

Comment: Key F1 — такого не встречал вроде. Нет, иногда, конечно, не прочитываю по словам, если много технической информации, а визуально воспринимаю. Пи, конечно, не буду читать по цифрам. Я не математик, да, но олимпиаду по математике при поступлении на естественный географический факультет МГУ выиграл (там не один победитель).

Comment: Грамота не выдумывает правила, они либо берут их из справочников Розенталя, Лопатина и т.п., либо выводят их из литературы как закономерности. Вопрос в том, откуда они это взяли.

Comment: @oleedd это ваше имхо, которое я не собираюсь комментировать здесь.

Answer (score 2):

Все рекомендации правильного написания предлогов ***с*** и ***к*** перед цифровой формой числительного 2, в том числе приведённая в Кратком справочнике по оформлению актов Совета Федерации Федерального Собрания Российской Федерации: «Правильно с 2 по 20 мая (но: со второго по двадцатое мая)», обществом не отвергаются, но и не принимаются как обязательные, и это мягко сказано.

Хотя понятна логика визуальной упорядоченности и уравнивания, лежащих в основе таких рекомендаций, результаты поиска в НКРЯ — вбивались все месяцы года — показывают превышение числа ***со*** над ***с*** на два порядка и сигнализируют об их (рекомендаций) негромком бойкоте.

Возможно, это является причиной отсутствия строгих правил (их появления), так как почти все примеры «правильного» написания относятся к позапрошлому веку.

Comment: Спасибо, интересно! "Правильно **с** 2 по 20 мая" (у Вас предлога нету)? И ещё в последнем предложении непонятно, не видно противоречия. НЕ, что ли, не хватает?

Comment: Примеры «с 2-го» массово относятся к далёкому прошлому, и современные рекомендации — не новость, а возврат. Пока топчемся. Правил нет.

Comment: То есть в последнем предложении Вы так и задумали. Меня смущает противительный союз А, без НЕ перед ним как-то странно звучит.

Comment: @shampar Мне нравится ваш ответ и ваша статистика — очень интересно! Но вот **тут** иссомневалася вся: *Хотя понятна логика визуальной упорядоченности и уравнивания, **лежащих** в основе таких рекомендаций...* Мне *каэтся* (помните, у Райкина?), что надобно так: *Хотя понятна логика визуальной упорядоченности и уравнивания, **лежащая** в основе таких рекомендаций...* Или мне кажется, или я понимаю Ваши мысли не совсем правильно?

Comment: Эти слова ключевые, они и есть ответ на вопрос. Уровнять в ряду многих других.

Comment: Опять иссомневалась. **Уровнять** (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C) — сделать гладким, ровным. *Уровнять землю. Уровнять дорогу.* **Уравнять** (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C) — 1. Сделать равным, одинаковым по размеру, величине и т. п. 2. Сделать равным в каком-л. отношении (в правах, положении и т. п.). Думаю, что Вы имеете в виду второе значение — с "а". Или нет?

Comment: Смысл и в визуальной, и в правовой стороне уравниловки. Не до одинаковости в чем-либо, а до неотличимости.

Answer (score 1):

[Перед цифрой употребляется предлог *с: с 2 ноября.*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%81%D0%BE%202)

Однако...

[Вопрос № 270384](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=270384)

> С добрым утром. На вопрос (№ 223760) «Как правильно писать со 2 по 5
> мая? или с 2 по 5 мая? Интересует предлог с (со)?» Вы ответили:
> "Правильно: *с 2 по 5 мая*". А чуть позже в ответе на вопрос № 234970:
> Предлог *со*... употребляется перед формами слов... второе, второй...
> Итого: со 2 по…

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Противоречие решается так: перед цифрой 2 используется предлог С,
> перед словом-числительным - предлог СО.

[Вопрос № 275530](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%20275530)

> Здравствуйте! Как правильно: со 2 июня или с 2 июня? Спасибо.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Правильно: с 2 июня (с цифрой), *со второго июня* (при записи
> числительного буквами).

P. S. Ответ обоим комментаторам: такова письменная языковая традиция: ТАК УСЛОВИЛИСЬ, пришли к консенсусу (меж собой Высокая Филологическая Община). Типа на вопрос "почему?" наука ответа не даёт.

Comment: Ну да, Галин, подобные ответы я видел накануне (позавчера).

Comment: Вопрос в том, почему так.

Comment: ПыСы нарисовала.